# Serialize python class to C-type struct (with bit-padding) for sending over socket

Tags: c++, python-2.7, sockets, serialization

I have a server that accepts incoming packets as in following C++ struct:

```
struct data_point
{
    uint32_t    type           : 8;
    uint32_t    id             : 24;
    uint32_t    timestamp_sec;
    uint32_t    timestamp_msec : 10;
    uint32_t    status         : 4;
    uint32_t    value          : 18;
};
```

I making a python-based client that has the following `DataPoint` class:

```
class DataPoint :
    def __init__(self, type, id, sec, msec, status, value) :
        self._type = type
        self._id = id
        self._sec = sec
        self._msec = msec
        self._status = status
        self._value = value
```

How can I serialize the `DataPoint` to binary format and send over socket for the server to accept correctly?

Comment: Why don't you use json?

Comment: @yumetodo for reducing traffic the struct has been strictly designed, and I didn't make it.

Answer (score 0):

use `struct.unpack()`
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/struct.html#module-struct

and also you need to write binary operation manually...